# Merge Rows data with matching columns data from SQLite table?

Tags: sqlite

I want to query a table name **Lines** like this:

```
ID   Part        Count
---  ---------   ------------
1    5           234
2    5           846
3    5           234
4    6           585
5    6           585
6    7           465
```

and return the rows data like following :

```
 ID   Part        Count
 ---  ---------   ------------
 1    5           1314
 4    6           1170
 6    7           465
```

What I want is to merge the Count column value where Part column matches and return other rows as is.I know little about database and have tried many queries but not able to achieve the result that I want.

Comment: please remove mysql tag. and post the name of the table

Comment: Please define how ID is to be chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select Part, sum(Part) as Count from tableName 
  group by Part
```

Comment: You should probably not use ID when grouping by part.